# Permanently install an updating Ubuntu on USB drive

Tags: system-installation, usb-drive

I do know that some utilities can create a persistent Ubuntu on a USB drive, but as far as I know these installations never update the kernel and driver installations are not possible.

So the question is: is it possible to have a full fledged, updating Ubuntu installation running on a USB drive? Creating this installation would happen from a Windows 10 UEFI computer.

Comment: As answered below but there's one caveat: USB flash drives are designed with limited R/W cycles therefore they will wear out quickly if used as a regular system drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to install Ubuntu in any available drive including external HDDs or USB flash drives and it will behave pretty much as installed in HDD or SDD, albeit slower.

From Windows 10 you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create an installation media with a different USB flash drive than the one you will be installing to. Needless to say you cannot install to the same drive your booting the installer from.

Shutdown. Then insert both the drive you've made with Rufus and the one you intend to have Ubuntu installed on, boot from the former and follow instructions to install in the latter.